# How to get the for attribute of label element using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, attributes, label

Am trying to use Python for the first time, and working on Selenium.

Goal is to get the ID of the Input element.
Am trying to work with a page that generates random ID for Input element.  So cannot address that element by ID.  How ever i found that the element has a label, and the label says For="<Dynamic_ID_Of_Input>"

And it so happens the label has no other attribute either.

Here's what the page looks like

```
<div class="form-input">
    <label for="labeled-input-Asrf3PAYKRKRY1veHroMKxyxf">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="labeled-input-Asrf3PAYKRKRY1veHroMKxyxf" name="Asrf3PAYKRKRY1veHroMKxyxf" maxlength="79" class="" value="">
</div>
<div class="form-input">
    <label for="labeled-input-7Hgp_pSJn3iqZ3T_eRwBX5I5n">Last Name</label
    <input type="text" id="labeled-input-7Hgp_pSJn3iqZ3T_eRwBX5I5n" name="7Hgp_pSJn3iqZ3T_eRwBX5I5n" maxlength="79" class="" value="">
</div>
```

Here's what I have managed so far:

```
FName_ID = (driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[contains(text(), 'First Name')]//ancestor::div//input").get_attribute("id"))
print("FName_ID",FName_ID)
LName_ID = (driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[contains(text(), 'Last Name')]//ancestor::div//input").get_attribute("id"))
print("LName_ID",LName_ID)
```

the print output looks like this:

```
FName_ID labeled-input-Asrf3PAYKRKRY1veHroMKxyxf
LName_ID labeled-input-Asrf3PAYKRKRY1veHroMKxyxf
```

Am not able to figure out what is missing here.  Appreciate all help.

Thank You

Comment: It's not clear for me. What element are you trying to get here? What is the goal here?

Comment: Goal is to get the ID of the input element, that is attached to the label called First Name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
FName_ID = (driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[contains(text(), 'First Name')]/..//input").get_attribute("id"))
print("FName_ID",FName_ID)
LName_ID = (driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[contains(text(), 'Last Name')]/..//input").get_attribute("id"))
print("LName_ID",LName_ID)
```